# How to wrap img element with a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am going to wrap all my image with a div tag that has a class named image i'm doing just like the [jquery website](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/) but it doesn't work.
this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $( ".post img" ).wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" );
});
    </script>
```

and this is my html code:

```
<div class="post">
        <img src="some where" alt="here"/>
        <img src="some where" alt="here"/>
        <img src="some where" alt="here"/>
        <img src="some where" alt="here"/>                                    
    </div>
```

Comment: Works just fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/FCLPz/

Comment: Did you mean wrap all of them in the same DIV, or each image in a seperate DIV (which is what you're doing now) ?

Comment: Then what you have should work just fine ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop through the images and wrap them

```
$(".post img").each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).wrap("<div class='new'></div>");
});
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FCLPz/2/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

> i am going to wrap all my image with a div tag

In order to wrap all the images in a wrapper, you need to use [`.wrapAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) method instead.

```
$(".post img").wrapAll("<div class='new'></div>");
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wocizowo/1/edit)**.

However, for wrapping each image in a separate div, your code [is working](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/FCLPz/1/) for me.