# How to wrap picture tag around an img tag

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have this:

```
<img src="large/image.png" />
```

I want this:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:800px)" srcset="medium/image.png">
  <source media="(min-width:300px)" srcset="small/image.png">
  <img src="large/image.png" />
</picture>
```

I want to do it with PHP's DOMDocument and have tried this code:
(there may be more than one image in the html)

```
$domContent = $domDocument->loadHTML($html);
$images = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
  $picture = $domDocument->createElement('picture');
  // $pic_clone = $picture->cloneNode();

  $source = $domDocument->createElement('source');
  $source->setAttribute("media", "(min-width:800px)");
  $source->setAttribute("srcset", "path_large");
  $source->setAttribute("media", "(min-width:300px)");
  $source->setAttribute("srcset", "path_small");

  $src_clone = $source->cloneNode();
  $src_clone->appendChild($picture);

  $image->parentNode->replaceChild($src_clone, $image);
  $src_clone->appendChild($image);
}
```

This produces:

```
<source media="(min-width:300px)" srcset="path_small">
<picture></picture>
<img src="large/image.png"></source>
```

1. How to place the picture tag correctly?
2. How do I get both source tags ?
3. How can I avoid the closing source tag  ?

I just cant wrap my head around this...

PS: Dont bother about the image paths, those I will fix later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wrap img element with a div tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131009/how-to-wrap-img-element-with-a-div-tag)

Comment: Ehh, thats javascript (jquery) right?

Comment: Indeed, but the idea behind is quite similar, just write your html straight away and inject your img html in it. very simple...

Comment: Problem is that I have a chunk of html with paragraphs, headings etc. including one or more images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around to this code thanks to the hints from @swadhwa and @MaxiGui.
Really appreciate your feedback, thanks.

```
private function PictureWrapper($content=false) {

    $domDocument = new DOMDocument();
    $domContent = $domDocument->loadHTML("<html><head><meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'></head><body>" . $content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

    if (false === $domContent) {
        return $content;
    }
  
    $images = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName('img');
    if (0 === count($images)) {
        return $content;
    }

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $img_src = $image->getAttribute("src");
        $arr = pathinfo($img_src);
        $dirname = $arr['dirname'];
        $base = $arr['basename'];

        $img_medium = $dirname . "/medium/" . $base;
        $img_small = $dirname . "/small/" . $base;

        $picture = $domDocument->createElement('picture');
        $pict_clone = $picture->cloneNode();
        $image->parentNode->replaceChild($pict_clone, $image);
        $pict_clone->appendChild($image);
            
        $source = $domDocument->createElement('source');
        $source->setAttribute("media", "(min-width:800px)");
        $source->setAttribute("srcset", $img_medium);
        $src_clone = $source->cloneNode();
        $image->parentNode->replaceChild($src_clone, $image);
        $src_clone->appendChild($image);
            
        $source = $domDocument->createElement('source');
        $source->setAttribute("media", "(min-width:300px)");
        $source->setAttribute("srcset", $img_small);
        $src_clone = $source->cloneNode();
        $image->parentNode->replaceChild($src_clone, $image);
        $src_clone->appendChild($image);
    }
    $content = $domDocument->saveHTML();
    $content = str_replace('<html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" 
    http-equiv="Content-Type"></head><body>', "", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</body></html>', "", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</source>', "", $content);

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: This is my final solution, but I don't know how to close the question?  
edit: Oh, I can close/accept it tomorrow :o)

Comment: You accpt your own awnser. The question always remains open, unless closed for future refernces.

Answer (score 0):

you're appending it on `source` element instead of `picture`

replace this:

```
$src_clone = $source->cloneNode();
$src_clone->appendChild($picture);

$image->parentNode->replaceChild($src_clone, $image);
$src_clone->appendChild($image);
```

with this:

```
$src_clone = $source->cloneNode();
$picture->appendChild($src_clone);

$image->parentNode->replaceChild($src_clone, $image);
$picture->appendChild($image);
```

Comment: No, that wont do it, now I end up with only the source tag:
<source media="(min-width:300px)" srcset="path_small"></source>

Comment: @Hendrix I think you need to remove this line: `$image->parentNode->replaceChild($src_clone, $image);` what is the purpose of this line?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I adapted this code from a question here about wrapping a link.
I will try out some more things and then I''l get back here later. Thanks for your input.